# Edge connectivity using flow network

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

Find an algorithm for edge connectivity in undirected graph using flow networks. Try to use $O(m)$ edges.

So basically the flow network should be used as a "helper function" and the graph that I give this helper function should have $O(m)$ edges.

How can I do that? So far I know about Ford-Fulkerson algorithm and Dinic algorithm.